# US-County level - median income 1930 to 1990

Tags: usa, historical, income, county

I am looking for median income statistics per county for the time period from 1930 to 1990. I have found [these](http://www.census.gov/data/tables/time-series/dec/historical-income-counties.html) median income statistics from 1960 to 1990 at the US census bureau. However, I seem to be unable to find any earlier calculations at the county level. Do they exist? If so, where?

Comment: I've been meaning to respond to your question and finally remembered to do so. I checked NHGIS.ORG and found that it has county-level data with shape files for 1950, 1980, and 1990. It is not a complete set of data, unfortunately.

Comment: Thank you for the comment and sorry that it went unnoticed (by me) for so long. I am especially interested in the data from 1950 you mention but cannot seem to find it on NHGIS. Could you provide a link?

Answer (score 3):

I suggest you search IPUMS, which has variables going back to 1850: https://usa.ipums.org/usa/index.shtml

I quickly searched and found that at least, personal income has been evaluated going back to 1940: https://usa.ipums.org/usa-action/variables/group?id=income

But a more detailed search might be even more fruitful.

Comment: Thank you, I upvote your answer because it may be helpful for others with similar questions. For me, it is not completely satisfactory because this is income at the individual, not at the county-level which complicate things for me. Of course, I could collapse individuals onto the county-level but I would feel much better if I had pre-calculated, "official" statistics on county-level income which I presume must exist somewhere.